# Using existing VNET with Azure Function APP

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-functions, subnet, vnet

I have one `VNET` and `2 subnets` under that. One subnet is used to connect to an external Kafka server.

**VNET:** xx.xx.xx.0/26
**Subnets:** xx.xx.xxx.0/27 and xx.xx.xxx.32/27 (27 Available IPs each)

I wanted to test the `Kafka topics` using the `bootstrap server`. Is it possible to create a `Function App` and target that to the same existing subnet (that was used to connect to an external Kafka server.) So that, I can get a console in Azure to run the commands and test the Kafka topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   Since your Kafka Server is an external server and you have deployed a bootstrap-config server to connect and forward the Azure resources metadata to the Kafka server while also configuring the function app in the same subnet as the bootstrap server, you will need two subnets. As you can relate with P2S(Point-to-Site) connectivity where we connect two virtual machines, one is external and the other one is internal. For this type of connection, you require a VPN gateway and application gateway itself which will create another subnet.

•   Hence, from the above conclusion, you will require two subnets to create a connection between external Kafka server and function application hosted on Azure. You can also refer to the link below for more details on configuring and deploying a Kafka cluster and a function app on Azure within a closed virtual network. In this document, the architecture of the deployed resources implies that the Kafka server and the function app to be deployed will be hosted on different subnets within the same virtual network.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/collaborate-kafka-and-azure-functions-securely-within-closed/ba-p/2429394

Also, for more details on setting up the Kafka bootstrap server with other platforms, and similar resources in Azure, please refer to the below documented sample link: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension-sample-confluent/azure-functions-kafka-extension-sample-using-confluent-cloud/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet